# Emails are not received in Opencart 2.3

Tags: email, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I am using Opencart 2.3.0.2 version. I am facing issue with receiving emails from the store. I did the setting from System > Setting > Mail.

I am not getting emails from contact form or for any new order placed in the store.

[image]

I tried with SMTP and set hostname as ssl://smtp.gmail.com but in this case, when I submit contact form I am getting error

> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection refused)

I did search on this issue and found some solution on StackOverflow but none of them worked for me.

I tried simple mail function by creating a test page and that works for me.

I am trying to fix this issue from past 2 days but still didn't found any solution.

Help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common problem that emails somehow don't end up in the inbox they are supposed to when sent from a web server and there are loads of possible explanations but here are 3:

1. Your server is blocking them on purpose, which can be configured in cPanel as described here: https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/emails-not-arriving-using-smtp/
2. Your web server is thinking the destination inbox is on the server itself but you are using a remote mail service: https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/contact-form-not-sending-email/
3. Your web server doesn't have very good deliverability and emails are ending up in the spam folder, so use a separate SMTP to send: https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/how-to-stop-opencart-emails-going-to-spam-by-using-smtp/

Comment: Thanks for your you response. It was an issue with the server. The email limit exceeds due to which all emails are discarded.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, perhaps briefly list the steps here that you used to fix so that it will help others?

Comment: I created some subdomains and one of them got hacked. Due to malware, the email limit exceeds. And the emails going from the domain are discarded. I talked to the hosting support and they said that the email limit is exceeded. So, I removed all the subdomains and everything worked fine.